# How do I resolve the issue "Parent id must be numeric" when creating a new Google Cloud project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I tried to create a new Google Cloud project from the command line with:

```
$ gcloud projects create PROJECT_ID --folder=FOLDER_ID
```

But I got the error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.create)
INVALID_ARGUMENT: field [parent] has issue [Parent id must be numeric.]
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: Parent id must be numeric.
    field: parent
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help
  links:
  - url: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects
```

Looking at `gcloud project create --help`, it says:

```
 --folder=FOLDER_ID
    ID for the folder to use as a parent
```

How do I get the folder ID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike the `PROJECT_ID` (which must must start with a lowercase letter and can have lowercase ASCII letters, digits or hyphens), a `FOLDER_ID` is not the name of the folder -- instead, it's a number (hence the "Parent id must be numeric") error.

You can find the ID of your folder by searching for it by name in the Google Cloud console, it'll be in a box with a "Folder ID" label.